# Convert integer to minutes and seconds in multiple countdown timer

Tags: vb.net

I made multiple countdown timers that work separately. A value (integer) goes through complicated ifs and formulas then becomes label4.text. 2 other values go through the same process and they each go to label5 and label6. Everything works fine when I countdown from integer, but when I try to change them to "mm:ss" format. The countdown changes to 04:59 from 300 then suddenly changes to 00:03 then stops.

```
    Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

/////////The one without format change/////////
    If CInt(Val(Label4.Text)) > 0 Then
        Label4.Text = (CInt(Val(Label4.Text)) - 1).ToString
    End If

/////////This one I tried to change the format///////
    If CInt(Val(Label5.Text)) > 0 Then
        Label5.Text = (CInt(Val(Label5.Text)) - 1).ToString
        Dim Displaytime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Val(Label5.Text))
        Label5.Text = Displaytime.ToString(("mm\:ss"))
    End If

    If CInt(Val(Label6.Text)) > 0 Then
        Label6.Text = (CInt(Val(Label6.Text)) - 1).ToString
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: If you are just calculating time. You just need 1 timer. Store the start datetime of each and then just substract from the current time and the result timespan will have the proper value.

Comment: What code should I write?